# how to share captured bitmap image(via camera) pass between one fragment two another fragment?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-bitmap

I tried lot to capture image via camera pass one fragment to another fragment I tried several ways but I cannot do that please help me do that.

used intent and sharedpreference

app closing

Comment: Instead of passing bitmap just pass image path.

Comment: Can you add your code segment also

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to pass an object from one activity(fragment) to another. Most suitable one for your case is through Application class.

create an class extending Application

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

 public Bitmap myCameraImage;//(or private + getter/setter)

}
```

Then, inside your AndroidManifest, add this class with name attribute:

`<application android:name="<yourpackage>.MyApp"`...

Now you can access `myCameraImage` in every fragment or activity without trouble.

to access it in fragment:

`MyApp myApp = (Myapp) getActivity().getApplication();
 myApp.myCameraImage;`

to access it in activity:

`MyApp myApp = (Myapp)getApplication();
 myApp.myCameraImage;`

You can set this value in one fragment, access it in another one

Comment: I guess so: `how to share captured bitmap image(via camera) pass between one fragment two another fragment in android`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski would you show some courtesy of telling what's wrong